# Compare values while saving upon a model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

this is my model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    activate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now i want to do is , whenever some one from admin panel makes it true  , an email will be sent to this particular user whose account is activated.

But i want to sent mail only when the value becomes true from false. if the value is already true i dont want to send any mail .

tried this thing with post save , but it sends email after every save action on Profile Model

Comment: Do you want it to send an email when the value changes in the frontend or when its about to be or has been saved to the database?

Comment: i want to send an email if someone activated the user profile from front end . And when he click on save then the email should go to user , making him aware of his account activation . 
although my problem is solved , as the code provided by @stalk is working fine as per my needs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code, that will do it (used [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save)):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def profile_changed(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.activate:
        if not instance.pk:
            print "Send email to user here"
        else:
            activate_was = sender._default_manager.filter(pk=instance.pk)\
                .values("activate").get()["activate"]
            if activate_was != instance.activate:
                print "Send email to user here"
```